# Leaves are not maintained in any order in leave submission table. I want to create a view where I can make a monthly vector of it against employees

Tags: sql-server, database, view

There is a table in my database for leave submission. Leaves are being maintained without any order. I want to create a view where I can make a monthly vector of it against employees. `Emp_id` is a foreign key. `st_date` is the date starting date of leave and `end_date` is the date where leave duration will be ended

[image]

Comment: What is the question here? I see a picture of a table. What are you trying to retrieve from it?

Comment: it's a table for leave submission. I want to create a view where I can make a monthly vector if it against employees.

Comment: You said you want to make a monthly vector against it. Can you explain what that means? Realize we can't see your screen and have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do here.

Comment: please show some sample data and expected output.please take a look at below link to know how to ask question,to ge help fast https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If you want to aggregate the total leave per month, what should happen if a period of leave spans multiple months? Should it all be attributed to the first/last month, or some other logic?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to report on total leave days per employee per month:

```
SELECT emp_id As EmployeeID,
       DATENAME(YEAR,st_date) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MONTH,st_date)),2) AS [Month],
       SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,st_date,end_date)) AS DaysLeave
FROM Leave
GROUP BY emp_id,
         DATENAME(YEAR,st_date) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MONTH,st_date)),2)
ORDER BY emp_id,
         DATENAME(YEAR,st_date) + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MONTH,st_date)),2)
```

Note: this will treat any leave which spans multiple months as if it all occurred in the month the leave started. It also doesn't exclude weekends.